# Excel divide column per row formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel column (total per x) and row (cumulative values of y) and I want to calculate the %.

In the following example I'm trying to calculate for example :  `BQ18/BQ89`, then `BP19/BP89`, `BO20/B089` etc. My table is shown on the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally do not explicitly calculate percentage in Excel. You simply divide the 2 numbers and format the cell to show % instead of plain number. Try right-clicking the cell and choosing % format.

It seems I also have to mention the basic Excel mechanism of prefixing the reference with `$`. Try to enter this formula somewhere on your sheet:

```
=BC6/$BQ$89
```

Then go with the mouse cursor to the bottom right corner of the formula cell, grab it and drag it down without releasing the button. You will clone the formula. When you clone the formula in this way, `BC6` becomes `BC7`, `BC8`, `BC9` etc., while `$BQ$89` stays unchanged because it is prefixed with `$` sign. After you release the mouse button, grab it again and drag it to the right so as to create a whole table of ratios. Then format this table to show `%`. For further reference, [see eg here](http://www.notjustnumbers.co.uk/2011/05/excel-tip-dollar-sign-in-formula-fixing.html).

Comment: Thanks, however my question is how to calculate the division for all the values (column*row) not how to show % (once i calculated values using formula and not manually i can of course transform this to %). Many thanks

Comment: @Amine, I suspect you have basic Excel skills to learn...